# When to retrieve a profile information from a database

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm working on an app where users will have profiles in it.

I want to get a user profile information from a server and show that in a ListView

I know how to retrieve the data form a server by using Volley and JSON.

I'm asking about the logic of getting data for a specific user.
Do I get it when s/he logs in?
I want to keep them logged in, so when should can I get the data?

Comment: Getting the data and staying logged in seem unrelated. What is the actual question? Obviously, you should get the users information when they login, but ask yourself, what more do you really need other than a profile  username that you can't query later?

Comment: It seems to me that the real question is: `How to auto-login after the user successfully logged in once?`. Which has already been answered a godzillion times, here. And also outside SO. If you just wanted to google.

Comment: @Rotwang Thank you for answer. I know how to keep them logged in i am asking how to get his data such as his posts or something like that.

Comment: Simply put the data in some shared variables (or into a shared object), after loading the main activity